# TypeError: Operator == not compatible with types address and function () view returns (address)

Tags: solidity, tokens

i am developing a simple contract where i get this error:

```
TypeError: Operator == not compatible with types address and function () view returns (address)
--> dar.sol:181:17:
```

here is the code

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;


interface IBEP20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) external view returns (uint256 balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) external view returns (uint256 remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint256 tokens);
}
abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes calldata) {
        this; // silence state mutability warning without generating bytecode - see https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2691
        return msg.data;
    }
}

abstract contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    
    constructor () {
        address msgSender = _msgSender();
        _owner = msgSender;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender);
    }

   
    function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(owner() == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

    
    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
        _owner = address(0);
    }

   
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, newOwner);
        _owner = newOwner;
    }
}

interface IBEP20Metadata is IBEP20 {
   
    function name() external view returns (string memory);

    
    function symbol() external view returns (string memory);

    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
}


contract Berry is IBEP20, Ownable, IBEP20Metadata {
    mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;

    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    uint256 private _totalSupply;
    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;
    
    bool public paused;

    
    constructor() {
        _name = "Berry";
        _symbol = "Berry";
        _mint(msg.sender, 10000000000*10**18);
        
    }
    

    function name() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    
    function symbol() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public view virtual override returns (uint8) {
        return 18;
    }

 
    function totalSupply() public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }


    function balanceOf(address account) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }

    
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }
      
      


    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

   
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

   
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        uint256 currentAllowance = _allowances[sender][_msgSender()];
        require(currentAllowance >= amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds allowance");
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), currentAllowance - amount);

        return true;
    }

    
    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender] + addedValue);
        return true;
    }

    
    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        uint256 currentAllowance = _allowances[_msgSender()][spender];
        require(currentAllowance >= subtractedValue, "BEP20: decreased allowance below zero");
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, currentAllowance - subtractedValue);

        return true;
    }

    
    function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(sender != address(0), "BEP20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "BEP20: transfer to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        uint256 senderBalance = _balances[sender];
        require(senderBalance >= amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        _balances[sender] = senderBalance - amount;
        _balances[recipient] += amount;

        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }
 function sendMoney() public payable {

    }

    function setPaused(bool _paused) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "You are not the owner");
        paused = _paused;
    }

    function withdrawAllMoney(address payable _to) public {
        require(owner == msg.sender, "You cannot withdraw.");
        require(paused == false, "Contract Paused");
        _to.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
    
    function destroySmartContract(address payable _to) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "You are not the owner");
        selfdestruct(_to);
    }



    
    
    function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual onlyOwner {
        require(account != address(0), "BEP20: mint to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(address(0), account, amount);

        _totalSupply += amount;
        _balances[account] += amount;
        emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
    }

  
    function _burn(address account, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        require(account != address(0), "BEP20: burn from the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(account, address(0), amount);

        uint256 accountBalance = _balances[account];
        require(accountBalance >= amount, "BEP20: burn amount exceeds balance");
        _balances[account] = accountBalance - amount;
        _totalSupply -= amount;

        emit Transfer(account, address(0), amount);
    }

   
    function burn(uint256 amount) internal virtual onlyOwner {
        _burn(_msgSender(), amount);
    }

    
    function burnFrom(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        uint256 currentAllowance = allowance(account, _msgSender());
        require(currentAllowance >= amount, "ERC20: burn amount exceeds allowance");
        _approve(account, _msgSender(), currentAllowance - amount);
        _burn(account, amount);
    }

    
    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(owner != address(0), "BEP20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "BEP20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

   
    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use `owner()` instead of `owner`, the error is you are comparing an address with a function type with the == operator. owner is the function name

```
function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }
```

and you need to invoke it like this `owner()` to get the address. _owner is a private and used in the abstract code.